# MATLAB ode45 not creating the right plot

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

So I was given a second order boundary value problem with y(0)=5 and y(20)=8.  We are supposed to use the shooting method with ode45 to approximate the solution and compare it to the actual solution.  I have already converted the equation to a first order equation and found the analytic solution (y1).  We are supposed to have the user input guesses of -1 and -.5, but when I do this the graph doesn't resemble the actual at all.  I have commented out the while loop we are supposed to use to get the solution to within a tolerance because I need the first part to work out.  I'm not really sure what the issue is...

f.m file

```
function xp=f(t,x)
xp=zeros(2,1);
xp(1)=x(2);
xp(2)=exp(-5*t)-x(2)-9.81*sin(x(1));
```

main.m file

```
clear
clc

syms t;
c = -1.783049298*10^(-4);
d = 7.000178305;

y1 = c*exp((1/7+2*sqrt(2)/7)*t)+d*exp((1/7-2*sqrt(2)/7)*t)+t-2;

errta = 1;

prompt = 'Enter a guess for the slope';
z = input(prompt);
guesses(1) = z;

[t,x]=ode45('f',[0,20],[5,z]);
result(1) = x(length(x),1);

z = input(prompt);
guesses(2) = z;

[t,x]=ode45('f',[0,20],[5,z]);
result(2) = x(length(x),1);

% while errta>0.000001
%      z = (guesses(2)+guesses(1))/2;
%      
%      [t,x]=ode45('f',[0,20],[5,z]);
%     if x(length(x),1)>8
%         guesses(2)=z;
%     end
%     
%     if x(length(x),1)<8
%         guesses(1)=z;
%     end
%     
%     errta = abs(-.82857121689-z);
% end

plot(t,x(:,1),'r')
title('ode45 vs actual')
hold on

ezplot(y1,[0,20])
hold off
```

Comment: Is matlab really intelligent enough to recognize the end of function `f`? Or is that only from the presentation here? -- The function `y1` has nothing to do with the damped forced pendulum in the ODE equations. More precisely, there is no exact solution to be found.

Comment: sorry, that function is a separate f.m file.  i just edited it in the question

Comment: Still, your `y1` is solution to `7*y''-2*y'-y=-t`, quite different from the ODE `y''+y'+9.81*sin(y)=exp(-5*t)` that you are solving numerically.

Answer (score 0):

```
x''+x'+9.81*sin(x)=exp(-5*t)
```

as used in the `odefunc f` is a damped pendulum with some exponentially decreasing forcing. As such one can expect that at `t=20` an equilibrium or stationary point is reached. Those are precisely known as `x=2*pi*k`. Thus the mapping from the initial velocity to the final position will resemble a step function and the bisection function will find the almost vertical segment where the final value 8 resides on. But probably not the point where the final value is exactly 8. Make a plot for initial velocities ranging from 5 t0 10 to see this effect.

---

The exact solution named `y1` belongs to the differential equation

```
7*x''-2*x'-x=-t
```

The relation between initial velocity and final position is nearly linear with the solution `v0=-0.828571216889` which appears to be independent of the step size of the numerical solver. This value is also consistent with the proposed initial guesses.